# Videos not playing with lightGallery

Tags: javascript, html5-video, lightgallery

In a web project, I need to lay out a gallery using justifiedGallery and also create lightbox treatment using lightGallery. Now, the photos work fine, whereas videos don't play:

[image]

[Here](https://codepen.io/dense-set/pen/XWGdZem) is the CodePen which demonstrates the problem.

**HTML:**

```
<p>The first item is a YouTube video. But it doesn't play!</p>

<div id="gallery">
  <a data-src="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIUJfXk3_3w" data-poster="https://img.youtube.com/vi/EIUJfXk3_3w/maxresdefault.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/EIUJfXk3_3w/maxresdefault.jpg" />
  </a>

  <a data-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605973029521-8154da591bd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=80">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605973029521-8154da591bd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=240&q=80" />
  </a>
  <a data-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526281216101-e55f00f0db7a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=80" >
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526281216101-e55f00f0db7a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=240&q=80" />
  </a>
  <a data-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1418065460487-3e41a6c84dc5?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=80" >
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1418065460487-3e41a6c84dc5?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=240&q=80" />
  </a>
  <a data-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505820013142-f86a3439c5b2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=80" >
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505820013142-f86a3439c5b2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=240&q=80" />
  </a>
  <a data-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477322524744-0eece9e79640?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=80" >
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477322524744-0eece9e79640?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=240&q=80" />
  </a>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
$("#gallery")
  .justifiedGallery({})
  .on("jg.complete", () => {
    lightGallery(document.getElementById("gallery"), {
      plugins: [lgVideo]
    });
  });
```

Plus, I use the following settings:

**External stylesheets** (loaded in the following order):

1. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/css/lightgallery.min.css
2. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/css/lg-video.min.css
3. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justifiedGallery/3.8.1/css/justifiedGallery.min.css

**External scripts** (loaded in the following order):

1. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js
2. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/lightgallery.min.js
3. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/plugins/video/lg-video.min.js
4. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justifiedGallery/3.8.1/js/jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js

---

Can someone please help me get the videos working correctly?

---

Note that this mix of photos and playable videos is documented in the [official documentation](https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/demos/mixed-contents/):

[image]

Comment: _"The photos work fine, whereas videos don't play"_ Do you have any web space to put an example demo page of your code attempt? The CodePen doesn't work (there is no gallery lightbox for any thumbnail items).

Comment: @VC.One Strange. It's working fine on my end. Can you [look at it](https://codepen.io/dense-set/pen/XWGdZem) one more time? I updated the external stylesheet and script settings to use the latest versions.

Comment: @VC.One Hold on! It looks like, it just worked! It might have been an issue of using outdated versions. I will confirm soon.

Comment: Your codePen works fine now as a lightbox (even the Youtube video plays ok). Tested in Chrome for Windows.

Comment: So yes, updating the CDN's did the trick.